# Is there a faster/optimisable way to find unique combinations from a set/list of unique elements in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, combinations, cudf

I am trying to find all the possible **unique combinations out of n elements, taken m at a time.** I have used **itertools.combinations** for the same and I have **n=85**.
So when I'm finding combinations for **m=5**, the number of combinations produced are about 3 cr and it is taking a lot of time, since as of now, the elements are a list of strings, or more precisely, they're columns in the alphabetical fashion, **not numerical indices**. I am currently working with **pandas** and itertools.combinations, would like to know if the process of finding combinations could be **parallelised**, to give same results every time upon further calculations that I perform on the columns further, or whether **GPU dataframes, like cuDF** might optimise this, although it doesn't look like it. Also, could converting the column names into numbers and then converting it into a **numpy array** to work on while finding combinations work faster? 
Please also suggest solutions where this could be done faster in some other programming language as well. 
Not a very good programmer. Would love to see some mathematical and programmatic solutions with a **complexity analysis.**

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly a complexity analysis problem, and there's no way to parallelize it in a way that will be satisfying. With `n=85` and `m=5`, there are `85^5 = 4437053125` possible combinations, including reversals and duplicates.

The fastest way that I know of using a GPU to explore this space is with cuGraph. Exploring all 4437053125 combinations is simply a breadth first search, though even with a GPU I expect it to take a very long time.

Artificial Intelligence is the study of methods of finding useful solutions inside of problem spaces that are too big to fully explore. A* or greedy search could give you a good solution, quickly, assuming that there is some metric that you are trying to optimize among the `85^5` total combinations.